# Why doesn't Unity provide support for subtraction and addition operations between Quaternions?

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions

When updating an orientation in quaternion form with an angular velocity, the process is as follows:
[image]
However, when I do this in Unity, an error occurs:

> Operator '-'/'+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Quaternion' and 'Quaternion'.

Are subtraction and addition operations not defined for quaternions?

(I'm not referring to anything about quaternion inverses which I already know)

Comment: Yes, there are [no operators](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) defined for adding or subtracting in Unity. I don't really know why, but my guess is that for a long time Unity never expected a scripter to use Quaternions directly at all, especially considering the text in the documentation.

Comment: No they are not defined for Unity's `Quaternion` - maybe I'm getting this wrong but isn't it basically the same as using [`Quaternion.ToAngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.ToAngleAxis.html), increase the angle and use it again in [`Quaterinon.AngleAxis`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.AngleAxis.html) ? As already mentioned by @MaxPlay above .. they don't expect anyone to directly (want to) deal with quaternions

Comment: @SZYoo Note that the formula you use is a numerical Euler step to integrate the quaternion to the next position over a time dt using the instantaneous quaternion derivative formed from w and q. However, even if Unity accepted this, it would lead to non-unit quaternions over time as the numerical integration error builds up. You would need to renormalize this periodically. Maybe better to just form the actual rotation and apply it to the original quaternion to get the next quaternion.